# Mobilefirst Desktop Browser Environment browser compatibility

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

does exists somewhere a kind of "Browser Compatibility Matrix" for projects with "desktop Browser Environment" in mobilefirst (7.1)?

Answer (score 1):

Like any MobileFirst-based app, it uses modern specifications of JS, CSS and HTML. So you need to use the browsers that match the technology that you intend on using. Better define your requirements in the question to receive a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the Mobile Browser Simulator in MobileFirst Platform Foundation? If yes, then you can refer to the following documentation to know the browser versions supported 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/wl_studio_tools/topics/cmbswl.html

Comment: Not exactly, I refer to specific Mobilefirst Web environment "Desktop Browser Web Page", so not (only) for simulation purpose...

Comment: MobileFirst Operations Console is that what you mean? Console where you manage your applications running on your mobile server? Based on product documentation - The Analytics page of the MobileFirst Operations Console supports the following browsers:

    Microsoft Internet Explorer version 10 or later
    Mozilla Firefox ESR or later
    Apple Safari on iOS version 7.0 or later
    Google Chrome latest version